# Facebook og:image gets images from post content

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-graph-api

Im having problems with Facebook not showing the proper images when I share.  I currently have an image set in the meta like so: `<meta property="og:image" content="http://xxx.com/images/fbthumb.jpg"/>`.  The problem is that this is the only image that shows up when I try to share a blog post.  If I have a featured image set, it will use that, but if no image is set, it defaults to the main fbthumb.jpg.

It seems like it used to scan the post and display the images in the post in the share window and you could choose which you wanted.  Im not getting that option now.  Any suggestions on how I need to code my og:image to show the images from the post rather than the default?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: what about the description content, are you getting the proper description when you try to share

Comment: Actually I just noticed that I dont have anything for og:description.  I only did the mandatory ones.  Everything looks fine in the linter though.  No errors.

Answer (score 3):

You should use multiple `og:image` meta tags to be able to select one of those images during share process.

If you omit 'og:image` meta than Facebook crawler will try to discover images from your page (this is not recommended).

There is a similar question [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images) which have [great explanation by OffBySome](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/7623986/155033) about how this works

Comment: Ah I see, the old link rel way of doing this is gone.  I thought I was losing my mind.  Okay so it seems to me like FB going through your post and grabbing images was the old and less desirable way.  Is there any way to have it do that with the og:image code?

Comment: I get that part, Im just trying to find out how to have it pull images from the post dynamically and put the image urls in the meta ;)